# Generic in type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I'm struggling with some generics.
The following is my setup:

```
interface I<T> { }

[...]
void Add<T>(T obj) where T : I<??> { }
```

How can I ensure that `T` in the `Add` method implements `I`?

Comment: Sorry - `Add` is NOT part of the interface `I` but a method on a different class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following signature will allow `Add` to take any `T` that implements `I<>` with any type parameters.

```
void Add<T,S>(T obj) where T : I<S> {
}
```

The downside of using this method signature is that type inference doesn't kick in and you have to specify **all** the type parameters, which looks downright silly:

```
blah.Add<I<int>, int>(iInstance);
```

A much simpler approach is to use the below signature:

```
void Add<T>(I<T> obj) {
}
```

Comment: `void Add<T>(I<T> obj)` did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the T parameter to add also.

```
void Add<TI, TAny>(TI obj) where TI : I<TAny>
```

Comment: `TI` is a generic parameter, not a generic itself, so you can't do `TI<TAny>`. Shouldn't your parameter just be `TI`? And your constraint should be `where T : I<TAny>`.